# Problem with strcmp usage

Tags: c

here is code

```
void process(char *input)
{
char *s;
char s1[100];
s=strtok(input,":");

while(1)
{
  if(strcmp(s,"regular")==0)// the strcmp is not working
  {
  s=strtok(NULL,",");
  if(s==NULL)
  break;
  }
}
```

actually the input to the function process is

```
i/p:          regular:ddf
```

but when i extract the token using strtok func and display s 
it is printing as "regular" correctly, but when i use "s" in strcmp(s,"regular")==0
it is not working. what is the problem????

Comment: if 1st the `if` fails, you're stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: @pmg y does the if fails? for this input: regular:df,

Comment: is the `"i/p:           "` part of the input?

Comment: when you print `s` use some markers to clearly see before and after the string: `printf("**%s**\n", s);`

Comment: You can add `printf("\"%s\"\n", s)` just above `strcmp` to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

Given your input, the `s` parameter to `strcmp` is

```
"          regular"
```

not

```
"regular"
```

Thus, no match, and, as a result, the code in the `if` block never runs and your `while` loop will never terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function (and a complete program showing how to use it) that does what I think you want.  Given the input of "i/p:          regular:ddf" it prints:

> Token found: "i/p"
>   Token found: "regular"
>   Regular!
>   Token found: "ddf"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void process(char * input)
{
    char * s = strtok(input, ": ");  // Get first token.  Colon AND space are delimiters.
    while(1)
    {
        if (s == NULL)
        {
            break;   // No more tokens.
        }

        printf("Token found: \"%s\"\n", s);
        if(strcmp(s,"regular")==0)
        {
            printf("Found \"regular\" token.\n");
        }

        s = strtok(NULL, ": ");  // Get next token.
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[] = "i/p:          regular:ddf";
    process(str); // Warning: process(str) will modify str
}
```

One big drawback to this approach, however, if that you can't call `strtok` anywhere else in the loop because this function relies on the internal state that is stored by `strtok` when it calls `strtok` with a NULL argument.